# Cannot not boot into Ubuntu 19.10 after installing Plymouth theme

Tags: boot, plymouth

I just started this Plymouth theme by apt install ./ from here:
https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1009776/
And my laptop cannot boot anymore, only a black screen not even grub, etc.
Could anybody help me get my Ubuntu working again?

Comment: you have a backup? Because this could be dangerous. boot a live session. Mount your / filesystem.  Remove the symlink  ´/etc/systemd/system/default.target` from your installed system and create a new softlink.  `ln -s /etc/systemd/system /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target` the idea is to force your system boot in text mode. If this work you can remove your plymouth theme.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it in another way.

I forced shutdown by holding down the power button and entered BIOS.
Without changing anything in BIOS I tried to boot again and after the purple boot page loaded I used Esc to see the text mode. Everything was OK but GDM could not start and it didn't get to the LOGIN page.

I used ctrl-alt-f2 to get to the command line. I entered my user and password.
then I tried this and it solved my problem:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And without even rebooting the system using ctrl-alt-f1 I got to the login page (gdm) and meanwhile I am using my Ubuntu to type this answer.

Comment: But now, every time I reboot the laptop, it stops just before the login page (gdm) with a purple screen and a cursor blinking. The only way to pass this, is to use ctrl-alt-f2 and then ctrl-alt-f1 again!